# Density of states from the Retarded Green's function for a rotating black hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes, ads-cft, density-of-states

I have been studying the scattering of a scalar field around a rotating black hole in the near-horizon extremal limit. The radial solution provides the retarded Green's function, just by taking the ratio between the coefficients of the asymptotic solution. Now, my intention is to compute the density of states, which from QFT is given by the following expression

\begin{equation}
\rho(\omega) = -\frac{1}{\pi}Im G_{ret}(\omega).
\end{equation}

My question would be if there is a more tractable way to compute the density of states? I have tried to compute the imaginary part but I don't know how to deal with the quotient of Gamma function, more precisely

\begin{equation}
 G_{R} = (-1)^{2\eta +1}(2i\omega)^{2\eta}\dfrac{\Gamma\left(1-2\eta \right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} -iq +\eta \right)}{\Gamma\left(1+2\eta \right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} -iq -\eta \right)} + \dots 
 \end{equation}

any suggestion about how to perform the calculation using brute force will be very appreciated. Thanks!